# SceneKit - Remove stitching line in edges borders

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d, scenekit, image-stitching

I'm displaying a texture on a cube (see [SceneKit - Map cube texture to box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949083/scenekit-map-cub-texture-to-box))
Things work well now, but the result show a light stitching line between some of the cube faces that I outlined here (you are inside the cube):

[image]

Any idea how I can get rid of that? The input texture looks like

[image]

So there is some discontinuity in the input. I'm using a custom SceneKit geometry that doesn't do much more than mapping this texture to a cube. You can find the relevant code in question mentioned above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961244/2054629

Answer (score 0):

As a hacky solution, I've changed the geometry of the cube to be slightly not cubic and more like [image]

So that the edges disappear (assuming the camera is inside). The texture is cropped a bit as a result, but this is much less noticeable.

I used to define the position of the 3 x 8 vertices as:

```
let _positions = [
  SCNVector3(x:-halfSide, y:-halfSide, z:  halfSide),
  SCNVector3(x: halfSide, y:-halfSide, z:  halfSide),
  SCNVector3(x:-halfSide, y:-halfSide, z: -halfSide),
  SCNVector3(x: halfSide, y:-halfSide, z: -halfSide),
  SCNVector3(x:-halfSide, y: halfSide, z:  halfSide),
  SCNVector3(x: halfSide, y: halfSide, z:  halfSide),
  SCNVector3(x:-halfSide, y: halfSide, z: -halfSide),
  SCNVector3(x: halfSide, y: halfSide, z: -halfSide),
]
let positions = _positions + _positions + _positions
```

and now I'm replacing the last line by:

```
let X = 0
let Y = 8
let Z = 16
func killEdgeStitching(positions: [SCNVector3], axis: Int) -> [SCNVector3] {
  var res = [SCNVector3]()
  let delta = Float(0.99)
  for pos in positions {
      var newPosition = SCNVector3(x: pos.x, y: pos.y, z: pos.z)
      switch axis {
      case X:
          newPosition.x *= delta
      case Y:
          newPosition.y *= delta
      default:
          newPosition.z *= delta
      }
      res.append(newPosition)
  }
  return res
}
let positions = killEdgeStitching(positions: _positions, axis: X) +
  killEdgeStitching(positions: _positions, axis: Y) +
  killEdgeStitching(positions: _positions, axis: Z)
```

I'll leave that out there, but hopefully someone will have a real answer!