# Odd border line on SCNPlane when alpha is set to 0

Tags: scenekit, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, scnprogram

I have an odd behaviour on the borders of SCNPlane, I trust any geometry would have that, which looks like similar to [SceneKit - Remove stitching line in edges borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961919/scenekit-remove-stitching-line-in-edges-borders)

I set transparency via SCNProgram and in fragment I run

```
float alphaBloom(float2 uv) {
uv *=  1.0 - uv.yx;   
float vig = uv.x*uv.y * 15.0;
vig = pow(vig, 3.95);
return vig;
}
```

Looks like the geometry is drawn with the correct alpha and at the end of it a line is drawn with the same color as the border, but alpha 1.

[image]

I do believe vertex and fragment shaders are ok and this looks like to me more a set/setting issue which I do not know yet.

**Is any flag to get rid of those?**

The same plane with diffuse transparent material with no program used is working ok.

Opaque is set to yes.
Setting it to NO will make the material alpha constant , I want it to change and be 0 towards the end of the surface. I do it through alphaBloom function set above.

Comment: do you have a screenshot? Is the `opaque` property set to `NO` on the `SCNProgram` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

In order to get rid of the extra line on the borders :

- .**isOpaque** = false
- **#pragma transparent** at the top of your program
- change your code so that it uses **premultiplied alphas**:
  return float4(0.0, 0.00000001, 0.0, 1) has to be
  return float4(0.0 * 0.00000001, 1.0 * 0.00000001, 0.0 * 0.00000001, 0.00000001) without .isOpaque

HTH!